# WMI creation instance event not received

Tags: wmi, sccm

I am registering for object creation event for class "SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment" to monitor deployments , code snippet is below :

```
_dhGCreation =  SINGLETON (CWMIEventManager)->subscribeToObjectCreation (L"SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment", this); 

void* CWMIEventManager::subscribeToObjectCreation (CComBSTR wmiClass, IWMIEventHandler* eh)
{

IUnsecuredApartment* pUnsecApp = NULL;
//IWbemUnsecuredApartment* pUnsecApp = NULL; 

HRESULT hres = CoCreateInstance (CLSID_UnsecuredApartment,
NULL, 
CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
IID_IUnsecuredApartment, 
(void**)&pUnsecApp);

DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();

LOG_DEBUG_2("CoCreateInstance done, GetLastError = %d, HRESULT = %d", dwErr, hres);
CEventSink* pSink = new CCreationEventSink (eh);
pSink->AddRef ();
LOG_DEBUG_0("pSink->AddRef");

IUnknown* pStubUnk = NULL; 

LOG_DEBUG_1("pUnsecApp = %d", &pUnsecApp);
pUnsecApp->CreateObjectStub (pSink, &pStubUnk);
LOG_DEBUG_0("pUnsecApp->CreateObjectStub");

IWbemObjectSink* pStubSink = NULL;
pStubUnk->QueryInterface (IID_IWbemObjectSink,
(void **) &pStubSink);
LOG_DEBUG_0("pStubUnk->QueryInterface");

/*
* The ExecNotificationQueryAsync method will call
* EventSink::Indicate method when an event occurs
*/
CComBSTR query =  L" SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA '";
query += wmiClass + "'";

CW2A printstr(query);

        // here smsProv is an instance to root/sms/site_<siteCode>
hres = smsProv->getWbemSvc ()->ExecNotificationQueryAsync (
CComBSTR (L"WQL"), 
query, 
WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
NULL, 
pStubSink);

/* Check for errors.*/
if (FAILED(hres))
{
pUnsecApp->Release ();
pStubUnk->Release ();
pSink->Release ();
pStubSink->Release ();
return 0;
}

return (void*) pSink;
}
```

When this registration happens, I recieve following error in SMSProv.log :

> Execute WQL  =select * from SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment~  $$<02-14-2017 13:59:55.472-330> Execute
>   SQL =select  all
>   SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.AssignmentID,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.LocaleID,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.AssignedUpdateGroup,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.AssignmentAction,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.Description,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.AssignmentID,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.AssignmentName,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.AssignmentType,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.Assignment_UniqueID,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.ContainsExpiredUpdates,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.CreationTime,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.DesiredConfigType,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.DisableMomAlerts,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.DPLocality,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.AssignmentEnabled,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.EnforcementDeadline,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.EvaluationSchedule,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.ExpirationTime,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.LastModificationTime,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.LastModifiedBy,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.LimitStateMessageVerbosity,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.LocaleID,SMS_UpdateGroupAssignment.LogComplianceToWinEvent...
>   ~*~*~e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\siteserver\sdk_provider\extnprov\extproviderclassobject.cpp(2190)
>   : ERROR ON INDICATE - likely Cancelled~*~*~  $$<02-14-2017 13:59:55.667-330> ERROR ON
>   INDICATE = (WBEM_E_CALL_CANCELLED)~  $$<02-14-2017
>   13:59:55.669-330> Results returned : 170 of -1~ 
>   $$<02-14-2017 13:59:55.675-330>

What could be the reason of this failure?

Answer (score 0):

don't do eventsinks. i've tried it and SMSProv.log generated a LOT of entrys.
Why? 
IMHO, the Database Call is not event based, so the sink generates a Database Query every 15ms or so. This will queued and u have to wait maybe an hour for sccm to return to normal function. Of course your connection to all consoles will be cancelled because the server had lots of Database queries to do.

Another idea is, that ur wbem provider is overloaded. Im experiencing this also at time i don´t know exactly why. scom have the same problem.or maybe our WMI namespaces are broken... i hope not, this would be a desaster....